# The difference between initrd and initramfs

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, boot

As far as I know, [initrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk) acts as a block device, thus requiring a filesystem driver (such as [ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2)). The kernel must have at least one built-in module for detecting filesystem of `initrd`. In this article, [Introducing initramfs, a new model for initial RAM disks](https://linuxdevices.org/introducing-initramfs-a-new-model-for-initial-ram-disks-a/), it is written that:

> But ramdisks actually waste even more memory due to caching. Linux is
> designed to cache all files and directory entries read from or written
> to block devices, so Linux copies data to and from the ramdisk into
> the "page cache" (for file data), and the "dentry cache" (for
> directory entries). The downside of the ramdisk pretending to be a
> block device is it gets treated like a block device.

What are `page cache` and `dentry cache`? In the paragraph, does it mean the data got duplicated because `ramdisk` is treated as a block device, thus all the data is cached?

In contrast, `ramfs`:

> A few years ago, Linus Torvalds had a neat idea: what if Linux's cache
> could be mounted like a filesystem? Just keep the files in cache and
> never get rid of them until they're deleted or the system reboots?
> Linus wrote a tiny wrapper around the cache called "ramfs", and other
> kernel developers created an improved version called "tmpfs" (which
> can write the data to swap space, and limit the size of a given mount
> point so it fills up before consuming all available memory). Initramfs
> is an instance of tmpfs.
>
> These ram based filesystems automatically grow or shrink to fit the
> size of the data they contain. Adding files to a ramfs (or extending
> existing files) automatically allocates more memory, and deleting or
> truncating files frees that memory. There's no duplication between
> block device and cache, because there's no block device. The copy in
> the cache is the only copy of the data. Best of all, this isn't new
> code but a new application for the existing Linux caching code, which
> means it adds almost no size, is very simple, and is based on
> extremely well tested infrastructure.

In summary, `ramfs` is just a file opened and loaded into memory, isn't it?

Both `initrd` and `ramfs` are zipped at compile time, but the difference is, `initrd` is a block device unpacked to be mounted by the kernel at booting, while `ramfs` is unpacked via cpio into memory. Am I correct? Or is `ramfs` a very minimal file system?

Finally, up until this day, the `initrd` image is still presented in the latest kernel. However, is that `initrd` actually the `ramfs` used today and is the name just for historical purposes?

Comment: you give good information while asking. I like this kinds of questions. thanks!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

#### Dentry (and inode) cache

The filesystem subsystem in Linux has three layers. The VFS (virtual filesystem), which implements the system calls interface and handles crossing mount points and default permission and limits checks. Below it are the drivers for individual filesystems and those in turn interface to drivers for block devices (disks, memory cards, etc.; network interfaces are exception).

The interface between VFS and the filesystem are several classes (it's plain C, so structures are containing pointers to functions and such, but it's an object-oriented interface conceptually). The main three classes are `inode`, which describes any object (file or directory) in a filesystem, `dentry`, which describes entry in a directory and `file`, which describes file open by a process. When mounted, the filesystem driver creates `inode` and `dentry` for its root and the other ones are created on demand when a process wants to access a file and eventually expires. That's a dentry and inode cache.

Yes, it does mean that for every open file and any directory down to root, there has to be `inode` and `dentry` structures allocated in kernel memory representing it.

#### Page cache

In Linux, each memory page that contains [userland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) data is represented by unified `page` structure. This might mark the page as either anonymous (might be swapped to swap space if available) or associate it with `inode` on some filesystem (might be written back to and reread from the filesystem) and it can be part of any number of memory maps, i.e., visible in the address space of some process. The sum of all pages currently loaded in memory is the page cache.

The pages are used to implement the [mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) interface and while regular read and write system calls can be implemented by the filesystem by other means, the majority of interfaces uses a generic function that also uses pages. There are generic functions, that when file read is requested allocate pages and call the filesystem to fill them in, one by one. For block-device-based filesystem, it just calculates appropriate addresses and delegates this filling to the block device driver.

#### ramdev (ramdisk)

Ramdev is regular block device. This allows layering any filesystem on top of it, but it is restricted by the block device interface. And that has just methods to fill in a page allocated by the caller and write it back. That's exactly what is needed for real block devices like disks, memory cards, USB mass storage and such, but for ramdisk it means, that the data exist in memory twice, once in the memory of the ramdev and once in the memory allocated by the caller.

This is the old way of implementing `initrd`. From times when initrd was rare and exotic occurrence.

#### tmpfs

Tmpfs is different. It's a dummy filesystem. The methods it provides to VFS are the absolute bare minimum to make it work (as such, it's excellent documentation of what the inode, dentry and file methods should do). Files only exist if there is corresponding inode and dentry in the inode cache, created when the file is created and never expired unless the file is deleted. The pages are associated to files when data is written and otherwise behave as anonymous ones (data may be stored to swap, `page` structures remain in use as long as the file exists).

This means there aren't any extra copies of the data in memory and the whole thing is a lot simpler and due to that slightly faster too. It simply uses the data structures that serve as cache for any other filesystem, as it's primary storage.

This is the new way of implementing `initrd` (`initramfs`, but the image is still called just `initrd`).

It is also the way of implementing "POSIX shared memory" (which simply means tmpfs is mounted on `/dev/shm` and applications are free to create files there and mmap them; simple and efficient) and recently even `/tmp` and `/run` (or `/var/run`) often have tmpfs mounted especially on notebooks to keep disks from having to spin up or avoid some wear in case of SSD disks.

Comment: Thanks. Very comprehensive. But one thing: old `initrd` is loaded as a block device, and as a result, it has to cache all the open file/directories (because a portion is used as a filesystem). However, `ramfs` is a filesystem image which content will be cached immediately in memory when the kernel unpackaged it, isn't it?

Comment: @Amumu - `initrd` is a block device, and simply put, block devices are cached. `initramfs` is not a filesystem image, it is just a compressed _cpio_ file; it is uncompressed into the `tmpfs`, just as when you decompress a _zip_ file.

Comment: @Amumu: Saying `initramfs` is immediately cached suggests there are two copies. But it's the exact oposite. It is stored in the cache, (ab)using it as the primary storage for the data, so the original compressed copy loaded by the bootloader may be immediately discarded.

Comment: @JanHudec *It is stored in the cache, (ab)using it as the primary storage for the data (...)* Isn't there a risk that cache gets discarded (as it's often the case with caches which are volatile by their nature) and thus data would get lost? Is there some mechanism which allows to *lock* such cache preventing this and if so what is it?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: As any sane cache, the page cache only discards content that is not modified compared to the backing store. Since there is no backing store for tmpfs, it can't discard the pages (if there is swap, it can use swap as ad-hoc store for pages that don't have their own).

Answer (score 100):

I think you are right in all.

The difference is easy to see if you follow the steps needed when booting:

### `initrd`

- A `ramdev` block device is created. It is a ram-based block device, that is a simulated hard disk that uses memory instead of physical disks.
- The `initrd` file is read and unzipped into the device, as if you did `zcat initrd | dd of=/dev/ram0` or something similar.
- The `initrd` contains an image of a filesystem, so now you can mount the filesystem as usual: `mount /dev/ram0 /root`. Naturally, filesystems need a driver, so if you use ext2, the ext2 driver has to be compiled in-kernel.
- Done!

### `initramfs`

- A `tmpfs` is mounted: `mount -t tmpfs nodev /root`. The tmpfs doesn't need a driver, it is always on-kernel. No device needed, no additional drivers.
- The `initramfs` is uncompressed directly into this new filesystem: `zcat initramfs | cpio -i`, or similar.
- Done!

And yes, it is still called `initrd` in many places although it is a `initramfs`, particularly in boot loaders, as for them it is just a BLOB. The difference is made by the OS when it boots.

Comment: What is "nodev" in `mount -t tmpfs nodev /root`? The only mentions of it that I saw in the manpages makes me think you forgot to specify the '-o' option.

Comment: @Adrian: The call to mount requires two arguments, the "device" and the "mountpoint", and usually you specify the type of mount with `-t <type>`. But `tmpfs` mounts do not have a device, because the make the data out of RAM memory. So the "device" argument to the mount `mount` for a `tmpfs` is required but not used, and can be any text you want, but as a convention it is usually `nodev`.

Answer (score 11):

**Minimal runnable QEMU examples and newbie explanation**

In this answer, I will:

- provide a minimal runnable Buildroot + QEMU example for you to test things out
- explain the most fundamental difference between both for the very beginners who are likely googling this

Hopefully these will serve as a basis to verify and understand the more internals specifics details of the difference.

The minimal setup is [fully automated here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8217e5508782827320209644dcbaf9a6b3141724#initrd), and this is the [corresponding getting started](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8217e5508782827320209644dcbaf9a6b3141724#qemu-buildroot-setup-getting-started).

The setup prints out the QEMU commands as they are run, and as explained in that repo, we can easily produce the three following working types of boots:

1. root filesystem is in an ext2 "hard disk":

   ```
   qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel normal/bzImage -drive file=rootfs.ext2
   ```
2. root filesystem is in initrd:

   ```
   qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel normal/bzImage -initrd rootfs.cpio
   ```

   `-drive` is not given.

   `rootfs.cpio` contains the same files as `rootfs.ext2`, except that they are in [CPIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) format, which is similar to `.tar`: it serializes directories without compressing them.
3. root filesystem is in initramfs:

   ```
   qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel with_initramfs/bzImage
   ```

   Neither `-drive` nor `-initrd` are given.

   `with_initramfs/bzImage` is a kernel compiled with options identical to `normal/bzImage`, except for one: `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE=rootfs.cpio` pointing to the exact same CPIO as from the `-initrd` example.

By comparing the setups, we can conclude the most fundamental properties of each:

1. in the hard disk setup, QEMU loads bzImage into memory.

   This work is normally done by bootloaders / firmware do in real hardware [such as GRUB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054578/how-to-run-a-program-without-an-operating-system/32483545#32483545).

   The Linux kernel boots, then using its drivers reads the root filesystem from disk.
2. in the initrd setup, QEMU does some further bootloader work besides loading the kernel into memory: it also:

   - loads the `rootfs.cpio` into memory
   - informs the kernel about it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89923/how-does-linux-load-the-initrd-image

   This time then, the kernel just uses the `rootfs.cpio` from memory directly, since no hard disk is present.

   Writes are not persistent across reboots, since everything is in memory
3. in the initramfs setup, we build the kernel a bit differently: we also give the `rootfs.cpio` to the kernel build system.

   The kernel build system then knows how to stick the kernel image and the CPIO together into a single image.

   Therefore, all we need to do is to pass the bzImage to QEMU. QEMU loads it into image, just like it did for the other setups, but nothing else is required: the CPIO also gets loaded into memory since it is glued to the kernel image!

Comment: For future reference it's better to cite the sources rather than just refer to them, i.e. to include all the necessary steps right here.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda hi, I usually do, but in this case I judged it would be to much code for an answer.

Comment: This is a very nice explanation and the website looks good to.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

To add another noteworthy difference between `initrd` and `initramfs` not mentioned in the excellent answer above.

- With `initrd` the kernel by default hands over to userspace `pid 1` at `/sbin/init`
- Newer initramfs however changes things up and executes `pid 1` at `/init`

as it could become a pitfall (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147688/24394)

Comment: Wasn't it PID 1?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: Definitely. PID 0 is an idle-CPU metaphor, PID 1 is - in most respects - a normal process.